# Assigning an array's elements to another array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] b = new int[4];
        b=a;

        for (int x : b)
            System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

`b` array can take 4 elements, but I insert 5 five elements of `a` array into b. The output is `1,2,3,4,5`. How is that possible in Java?

Comment: you want to insert 5 elements into b?

Comment: You've lost me, can you elaborate on what you're attempting to achieve? Also what isn't working as expected? Ps. `b=a` reassigns `b` to the array of `a`. It does not copy the contents of `a` into `b`

Comment: this code runs.And no error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` and `b` are *reference* variables. After initialization you effectively had something like this:

a -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b -> [0, 0, 0, 0]

When you do `b=a`, you are only reassigning `b` to reference the array that `a` is referencing, and the array that b *was* initialized with is no longer referenced at all. So, you now have:

(a and b) -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing b=a; you're overwriting your previous array b so that array b becomes your array a which has a size of 5.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning `new int[4]` to `b`, you are creating an empty `int` array with length 4. If you write `b = a`, you completely dispose of that newly created array by overwriting it with array `a`, which has a length of 5 and the content of `a`. Thats why the output in your question is `12345`.

I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is fill up array `b` with the values from array `a`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

But you can not insert the 5 values of `a` into array `b` which only has a length of 4.

Comment: Output of this code is 12345.I can't understand how

Comment: There's no output in this code, so what are you referring to exactly?

Comment: ı typed your code.And the output is 1234.But above code's output is 12345

Comment: Yes. As I said, by writing `b = a`, you're essentially disposing of your array `b` and you overwrite it with array `a`. Thats why the output in your question is 12345.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote b=a, b and a became aliases. 
b is now pointing to a.
Now if you change anything in a, it will also be changed in b and vice versa

See [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-does-java-handle-aliasing)